# Read & write in csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to fetch data from a FTP server every 5 minutes .with that data i need to do some process like fetching high,low values.For this i'm converting the .sec.gz to a csv(csv is comfortable for me identify the valuse).have to process around 4000 lines in a single file.likewise have to do for every 5 mins in a day.Firstly i'm retreiving a csv and then i'm replacing the header in that csv.In this process some of the files got stucked with incomplete data in the second csv.

My code is:

```
ip="ip address"
password='password'
file_connect=[]
file_sec=[]
interval=1
starttime=time.time()

for interval in range(1000):
    ftp=FTP('ip address')
    ftp.login('username',password)
    #print "File List:"
    files=ftp.dir()
    date_filename='c:/DATA_INTV_NEW/'
    filematch='C:/DATA_INTV_NEW/*'
    filer=ftp.nlst(date_filename)
    for files in filer:
        if files!='C:/DATA_INTV_NEW/June062014':
            data1=files
            #print data1
    date_a=data1.split('/')
    date_b=date_a[2]
    #print date_b
    day_all=date_b[-6:-4]
    year_all=date_b[-4:]
    month_all=date_b[0:-6]
    monthDict = {'January':'1', 'February':'2', 'March':'3', 'April':'4', 'May':'5', 'June':'6', 
                                'July':'7', 'August':'8', 'September':'9', 'October':'10', 'November':'11', 'December':'12'}
    month_all = monthDict[month_all]
    Date=day_all+"/"+month_all+"/"+year_all
    #print Date
    filenames=ftp.nlst(filematch)
    #print filenames
    mypath1='C:\\test\\'+date_b
    #os.makedirs(mypath1)
    #if (interval==1):
      #  mypath1='C:\\test\\'+date_b
        #os.makedirs(mypath1)

    for file_ in natsorted(filenames):
        if ((file_ not in file_connect) & (file_ in filenames)):
            if file_.endswith('.sec.gz'):
                file_c=file_.split('/')
                file_d=file_c[3]
                print file_d
                Files=date_b+'\\'+file_d
                print Files
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR C:/DATA_INTV_NEW/'+Files, open(mypath1+'\\'+file_d, 'wb').write)
        file_connect.append(file_)
    ftp.quit()
    #time.sleep(60)

    #Setting the path
    path = mypath1+'//*.sec.gz'   
    file_s=glob.glob(path)

    #Creating a historical data csv where all the data to be fed
    fl=open(mypath1+"//final2.csv","ab")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fl, fieldnames = ["S No", "Instrument Name", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "V" ,"Time" , "Date"])
    writer.writeheader()

    header = ["Instrument Name", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "V", "Time", "Date"]

    #Setting the start time as 9:15 am
    start_time=timedelta(hours=9,minutes=15,seconds=0)

    #Real process
    #if (files==file_s):
    for file_group in natsorted(file_s):
        if ((file_group not in file_sec) & (file_group in file_s)):
            f = gzip.open(file_group, 'rb')
            a=f.read()
            def stripped(x):
                return "".join([i for i in x if 31 < ord(i) < 127])
            b = stripped(a)

            if 'OPT' in b:
                c=string.split(b, 'OPT')

            #Stripped Opt symbol is added again
                for line in c:
                    if line[0:2]!='FUT':
                        line='OPT'+line
                        d=line

                    #Split lines into lines wrt Futures
                    if 'FUT' in d:
                        e=string.split(d,'FUT')

                        #Stripped fut symbol is added again
                        for line in e:
                            if line[0:2]!='OPT':
                                line='FUT'+line

                        #Separating the fields using Comma
                    i=0

                    #Conversion to list

                    g=list(line)
                    for g[i] in g:
                        if (i==5 or i==16 or i==28 or i==39 or i==42 or i==44 or i==55 or i==68 or i==79 or i==92 or i==103 or i==116 or i==127 or i==139 or i==150 or i==161 or i==172 or i==183 or i==194 or i==205 or i==216 or i==228):
                            g.insert(i+1,",")

                        i+=1
                        #Conversion back to string

                    h="".join(g)


                    #Writing into .txt or .csv file

                    num, ext = os.path.basename(file_group).split(".", 1)

                    output_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_group), "%s.csv" % (num,))

                    fn=open(output_filename,"ab")
                    fn.write(h + '\n')
                    fn.close

                #Removing Blank & none types    
                with open(output_filename,"rb") as inf:
                    next(inf)  # skip header row
                        #Adding header
                    num1, ext1 = os.path.basename(file_group).split(".", 1)
                    output_filename1 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_group), "%sa.csv" % (num1,))
                    f1=open(output_filename1,"ab")
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(f1, fieldnames = ["Instrument Name", "Symbol", "Expiry Date", "Strike Price", "Option Type","Market Type", "Buy Price", "Buy Quantity", "Sell Price", "Sell Quantity", "Last Traded Price", "Total Traded Quantity", "Average Traded Price", "Open Price", "High Price", "Low Price", "Close Price", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "V", "Quant", "Time", "Date"])
                    writer.writeheader()
                    #Removing emptylines
                    for line in inf:
                        if not line:
                            empty_lines += 1 
                            continue
                            #print line
                        count_c=1
                        g1=list(line[count_c] for count_c in range(23)) 
                        h1="".join(g1)
                        f1.write(h1)     
                    f1.close  #stucking in this part


            start_time=start_time+timedelta(seconds=300)
        file_sec.append(file_group)
    time.sleep(300.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 300.0))
```

Please help me to solve the issue.I'll show the output what i'm getting.For example my readable file has contents:

```
OPT{T                                                               
OPTSTK  AMBUJACEM   24/12/2014  240 CE  N   3.1 2000    3.3 4000    3.25    24000   3.21    4   4   2.9 3.5
OPTSTK  BPCL        24/12/2014  820 CE  N   6.85    1500    7.35    1500    7   21000   7.42    8.15    8.75    6.95    7.7
OPTSTK  DIVISLAB    24/12/2014  1750    CE  N   36.4    1500    48.2    375 46.05   0   0   0   0   0   46.05
```

in destination file:

```
Instrument Name Symbol  Expiry Date Strike Price    Option Type Market Type Buy Price   Buy Quantity    Sell Price  Sell Quantity   Last Traded Price   Total Traded Quantity   Average Traded Price    Open Price  High Price  Low Price   Close Price
OPTSTK  AMBUJACEM   24/12/2014  240 CE  N   3.1 2000    3.3 4000    3.25    24000   3.21    4   4   2.9 3.5
OPTSTK  BPCL        24/12/2014  820 CE  N   6.85    1500    7.35    1500    7   21000   7.42    8.15    8.75    6.95    7.7
OPTSTK  DIVISLAB    #here columns are missing
```

Comment: Close files with the close() method to ensure that all buffered data has been flushed to the file.

Comment: u mean not to use f1.close()

Comment: You have to do `f1.close()` and not `f1.close` as the latter will only return a file close method instance

Comment: The code as listed doesn't include parenthesis on the close calls.  You will need to add them.

Comment: Okay.Atlast my issue got resolved....Thank u so much Austin Philips & Bhargav Rao